# why is the below list count method for Python3 not working.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, counting

I am trying to use a list.count() method however i am getting the count as 0 in output which shouldn't happen.

```
basket=[1,8,4,3,6,4,5]

count=basket.count([4, 8])

print(f'The count of {basket[6]} & {basket[2]} is',count)
```

The Output is appearing as 0, where it should be 1 & 2

Is their something which i am doing wrong.?

Comment: .count([4, 8]) checks for the existence of [4, 8] in the list, which is zero

Comment: Why do you think the output should be 1, 2? What's `basket[6]` meant to represent.

Comment: also print(f'The count of {basket[6]} & {basket[2]} is',count) doesnt make any sense with your count operation

Comment: It seems weird to hard-code the indexes into the output like that, especially given that shows 4 and *5*, not 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to @Joshua Varghese answer - to make it work *exactly* the way you intended:

```py
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter
basket=[1,8,4,3,6,4,5]

count=itemgetter(4,8)(Counter(basket))

print(f'The count of {basket[5]} & {basket[1]} is',count)
```

Prints:

```py
The count of 4 & 8 is (2, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you @Grzegorz Skibinski

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation on `list`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> `list.count(x)`
>
> Return the number of times `x` appears in the list.

So `basket.count([4, 8])` will count how many times the whole list `[4, 8]` appears in `basket`. `basket` doesn't contain *any* lists at all, so you get zero.

Comment: Thanks for this information. So how can i print the number of times the value 4 and 8 appears in the list.?

Comment: @NeilBagchi, with a loop over `[4, 8]`, like `list(map(basket.count, [4, 8]))`

Answer (score 0):

`count([4, 8])` checks for the existence of `[4, 8]` in the list, which is zero.
To find the count of 4,8 :

```
basket=[1,8,4,3,6,4,5]
print(f'The count of {basket[2]} & {basket[1]} is',','.join(str(basket.count(i)) for i in [4,8]))
```

or simply:

```
from collections import Counter
count = Counter(basket)
print('The count of 4 & 8 is',count[4],',',count[8])
```